Determine the value of the sum of all elements of the set $A=\{ x \in \Bbb R | \frac{3x^2+5x+2}{x^2+x+1}\in \Bbb N\}$
The problem
Determine the value of the sum of all elements of the set
$A=\{ x\in \Bbb R : \frac{3x^2+5x+2}{x^2+x+1}\in \Bbb N\}$
my idea
I wrote $3x^2+5x+2=(3x+2)(x+1)$
For $\frac{3x^2+5x+2}{x^2+x+1}$ to be natural we need $x^2+x+1 | 3x^2+5x+2$ also we know that $x^2+x+1 | x^2+x+1, x^2+x+1| 3x^2+3x+3$ by decreasing them we get that $x^2+x+1 | 2x-1$ and by multiplying it with x we get that $x^2+x+1| 2x^2-x$ also $x^2+x+1|2x^2+2x+2$ and by decreasing them again we get that $x^2+x+1| 3x+2$
so we know that $x^2+x+1| 2x-1$ and $x^2+x+1| 3x+2$
which means that $x^2+x+1| 6x-3$ and $x^2+x+1| 6x+4$ and by decreasing them we get that
$x^2+x+1 | 7$ which means that $x^2+x+1=7,1=> x(x+1)=6,0$
so we got $x=0,-1,2,-3$
Are these the only values?
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

You are missing some values of $x$, the set $A$ will be $A = { -1,-2/3,-1\pm 1/\sqrt{2},0,-3,1/2}$. Try to find a range of natural values $k$ such that $3x^2+5x+2 = k(x^2+x+1)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

@Sam But how did you find them in a mathematical way?

For $x=-3$, the output will be $2$ which is a natural number. @IONELA

@Sam Oooo...sorry i calculated them wrong. But tho how do i find the other values

The solution of @Sam is good. It's just another viewpoint one can see.
Observe that, $\dfrac{3x^2+5x+2}{x^2+x+1} = 3 + \dfrac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1} \in \mathbb N \iff \dfrac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1} \geq -2$. That is $\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1} \in \{-2,-1,0\} \cup\Bbb N$. But it can be easily observed that $\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1} < 1 ~\forall~ x \in \Bbb R$. Hence $\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1} \in \{-2,-1,0\}$.


$\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1} = 0 \iff x = 1/2.$
$\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1} = -1 \iff x = 0,-3.$
$\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1} = -2 \iff x = -1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$


Hence sum of all these elements will be $-\dfrac{9}{2}.$

I proceeded as follows: (I am assuming that $0$ is natural, but this will not affect the approach)

Find all natural numbers $k$ such that $f(x)=\dfrac{3x^2+5x+2}{x^2+x+1} = k$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We see a quadratic equation $(3-k)x^2+(5-k)x+(2-k)=0$ whose discriminant is $D = -3k^2+10k+1$. We require $D>0$ (so that $x \in \mathbb{R}$), from which we obtain $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$.
Solving four quadratic equations: Correspoinding to these values of $k$, we get $$\begin{gather*} k=0, \quad x^2+\frac{5}{3}x+\frac{2}{3}=0 \implies x=-1,-\frac{2}{3}\\  k=1, \quad x^2+2x+\frac{1}{2}=0 \implies x=-1\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ k=2, \quad x^2+3x=0 \implies x=0,-3\\ k=3, \quad 2x-1=0 \implies x=\frac{1}{2}\\\end{gather*}$$
This gives us the set $$A = \left\{ -1,-\frac{2}{3},-1\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,-3,\frac{1}{2}\right\}.$$
However, if you just want to sum all the elements of $A$. Then using Vieta's formulas, the sum is $$-\frac{5}{3}-2-3+\frac{1}{2} = \boxed{-\frac{37}{6}}$$
If $0$ is not considered a natural number then we simply remove the $k=0$ quadratic, and the sum is therefore $-\frac{9}{2}$.


Nice and elementary. The first step is in my opinion the most key observation (and especially that the discrimination happens to be a negative-leading coefficient quadratic).
